# asp.net mvc + knockout + ajax partial load + reuse viewodel and load different data within the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In a single asp.net MVC page, I've to show 3 reports of same layout/structor. So I created a page that generated a report using Knockout databind and 10 reports are generated by passing some additional parameters.

I tried to load all 3 reports using Ajax partial view and by this way I'm populating those 10 reports in one single page.

Now I happen to see a strange issue, the last report data appears for all the 3 reports though the data for each report is different. Anyone knows how to handle this issue ?

**Main Page View, where I call 3 reports via Ajax call.**

```
 <div id="RecentlyAddedReport" ></div>
    <div id="RecentlyConsultedReport"></div>
    <div id="RecentlyPrescribedReport"></div>

    <!-- start here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            AjaxLoadReport('RecentlyAddedReport', 'Patient/Report?type=RecentlyAdded&name=Recently Added');
            AjaxLoadReport('RecentlyConsultedReport', 'Patient/Report?type=RecentlyConsulted&name=Recently Consulted');
            AjaxLoadReport('RecentlyPrescribedReport', 'Patient/Report?type=RecentlyPrescribed&name=Recently Prescribed');
        });

        function AjaxLoadReport(reportType, actionURL) {
            var resultDiv = $('#' + reportType);
            $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: actionURL, data: {},
                success: function (response) {
                    resultDiv.html('');
                    resultDiv.html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Report View - I call this same view for all the 3 reports**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TryHomeo.Web.UI.Models.UserControlViewData>" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<h1>
    <%:Model.ReportName%>
</h1>
<div class='loadingIndicator' title="Loading..."></div>
<ul id="<%=Model.ReportType %>" data-bind="template: { name: 'patient-template', foreach: patients}"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="patient-template">   
    <span>
        <li>
            <div>
                <a data-bind="text: PatientName"></a>- (<abbr class='timeago' data-bind="timeago: DatedString"></abbr>)
            </div>
        </li>
    </span>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // ReportViewModel View Model //
    function ReportViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.patients = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var objVM = new ReportViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(objVM);

    // Using jQuery for Ajax loading indicator 
    $(".loadingIndicator").ajaxStart(function () { $(this).fadeIn(); }).ajaxComplete(function () { $(this).fadeOut(); });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Patient/GetPatientReport/?type=' + '<%=Model.ReportType %>' + '&' + '<%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>',
            success: SetData,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
        });
    });

    function SetData(data) {
        objVM.patients(data);
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.timeago = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var $this = $(element);
            // Set the title attribute to the new value = timestamp        
            $this.attr('title', value);
            // If timeago has already been applied to this node, don't reapply it -    
            // since timeago isn't really flexible (it doesn't provide a public     
            // remove() or refresh() method) we need to do everything by ourselves. 
            if ($this.data('timeago')) {
                var datetime = $.timeago.datetime($this);
                var distance = (new Date().getTime() - datetime.getTime());
                var inWords = $.timeago.inWords(distance);
                // Update cache and displayed text..    
                $this.data('timeago', { 'datetime': datetime });
                $this.text(inWords);
            } else {
                // timeago hasn't been applied to this node -> we do that now!          
                $this.timeago();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to share some code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your view model to make sure that the reports have unique data? It may be that you're populating view model incorrectly and in turn populating 10 of the same object rather than having a problem with binding?

Comment: Have you looked to make sure that your knockout model is not having all of its reports set to the last one received? A quick way to check is with the javascript console on chrome or firefox (with firebug).

Comment: Added Source Code for your reference

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, document.ready doesn't get called on pages called via ajax and inserted into the DOM.

Comment: You have to call the applyBindings from your AjaxLoadReport's ajax callback